# Jquery UI Range Slider with associated Text Input Events (Failing)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have a range slider on my site for min-max price ranges.  On either side of the slider are two text input boxes.  I've created a callback function with the slider which adjusts the vals of the text boxes based on a val change within the slider.

At the same time, I would also like to adjust the values of the slider based on changes to th vals of the text boxes.  Right now, the change (also tried keyup) event that I'm binding on the text inputs are not changing the values (position) of the two range slider hands.  What's wrong here?

```
$('.price_slider').slider({orientation:"horizontal",range:true, animate:200,min:0,max:10000, step:100,value:0,values:[{{min_rent}},{{max_rent}}], slide:function(event,ui){
    $('input#lower_bound').val(ui.values[0]);
    $('input#upper_bound').val(ui.values[1]);
    }
    });


$('input#lower_bound').change(function(){
    $('.price_slider').slider("values",[$(this).val(),$('input#upper_bound').val()]);
});


$('input#upper_bound').change(function(){
    $('.price_slider').slider("values",[$('input#lower_bound').val(),$(this).val()]);
});
```

EDIT--

Matt, I saw your revision.  Just curious if your version is more efficient than mine.  Mine does seem to be working but I'm clearly not an expert:

```
    $lower.add($upper).change(function () {
    var lowEnd=parseInt($lower.val());
    var highEnd=parseInt($upper.val());

    if(highEnd>lowEnd){
        $slider.slider('values', 0, parseInt($lower.val(), 10));
        $slider.slider('values', 1, parseInt($upper.val(), 10));
    }
    else{
        $slider.slider('values', 0, parseInt($lower.val(), 10));
        $slider.slider('values', 1, parseInt($lower.val(), 10));
        $upper.val([$lower.val()]);
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For multi-handle sliders, you need to use `'values'` rather than `'value'` (which you're doing) but `'values'` takes this format:

  ```
  .slider( "values" , index , [value] )
  ```
- You probably want to enforce `max >= min` when setting the slider values based on the textboxes.
- You are passing the initial values to `.slider()` incorrectly, I don't know where that `{{...}}` nonsense came from (is that a jQuery template?).
- It's generally [not a great idea to use underscores in class names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/underscores_in_class_and_id_names). Use `-` instead of `_`.

The fixes:

```
var $slider = $('.price-slider'),
    $lower = $('#lower_bound'),
    $upper = $('#upper_bound'),
    min_rent = 1000,
    max_rent = 9000;

$lower.val(min_rent);
$upper.val(max_rent);

$('.price-slider').slider({
    orientation: 'horizontal',
    range: true,
    animate: 200,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000,
    step: 100,
    value: 0,
    values: [min_rent, max_rent],
    slide: function(event,ui) {
        $lower.val(ui.values[0]);
        $upper.val(ui.values[1]);
    }
});

$lower.change(function () {
    var low = $lower.val(),
        high = $upper.val();
    low = Math.min(low, high);
    $lower.val(low);
    $slider.slider('values', 0, low);
});

$upper.change(function () {
    var low = $lower.val(),
        high = $upper.val();
    high = Math.max(low, high);
    $upper.val(high);
    $slider.slider('values', 1, high);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/pLP2e/

Comment: Hi Matt, this was a great answer on a number of levels. It worked but have a couple of interesting comments. First, parseInt was not necessary. Second, the {{ brackets are Django template variables.  I set the range values based on the user's previous search. Finally, I created an extra conditional within the text input event handlers.  If $lower.val()> $upper.val() --> $upper.val([$lower.val()]).  Otherwise, the sliders were overlapping in the wrong direction and funky behavior was resulting

Comment: I changed the text input handler logic, did you see the latest version?

Comment: Hi Matt, I saw the changes just now. I see how yours works but mine (see edit above) seems to require less code. Generally curious why one would be preferably over the other.

Comment: Also, useful link re: underscores in CSS.  I wish I read that before I created a whole website full of class and ID underscores

Answer (score 4):

According to the [jQuery UI documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#method-values), `slider('values')` takes index as the second param and value as the third. Try this:

```
$('input#lower_bound').change(function(){
    $('.price_slider').slider("values",0,$(this).val());
    $('.price_slider').slider("values",1,$('input#upper_bound').val());
});


$('input#upper_bound').change(function(){
    $('.price_slider').slider("values",0,$('input#lower_bound').val());
    $('.price_slider').slider("values",1,$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks Darth.  I think that Matt beat you to the punch by a hair. But this was good info regardless

Comment: Yes he did, just as I was about to click the submit button, but since I typed it already I though I'd post it anyway. :)